# How to get the path to an existing file?

Tags: c++, file, path

I'm creating a file stream as follows:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(fileName);
```

Now how do I get the full path of the file named `fileName`? Note that `fileName` can be a relative path, and not a full path.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Comment: They have installed visual studio15, we can use any code that it supports

Comment: You'll have to use the RTM version of Visual Studio 2017, and compile with /std:latest (or similar option) to get experimental C++17 support.

Comment: I can download VisualStudio2017, but i will have problem when i try to compile my code at university, so i must use 2015 version...

Answer (score 2):

See : [std::basic_ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)

There is no method to retrieve the path used to open a stream. You'll have to track `fileName` yourself.

Edit: The question has been edited since I answered it. Getting the absolute path from a relative path is possible with C++17. See [std::filesystem::absolute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute).

Comment: I need something universal for homework, i am doing this at home, but it will be tested at university...Profesor want from us to generate path to a saved file..are u sure that there is no other way?

Comment: @IgorBeracka [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) offers new functionalities regarding the file system. I'm not 100% familiar with it yet but I don't now of any feature that let's you recover the path from an std::ofstream.

Comment: @IgorBeracka I've updated my answer in response to the edited question.

Comment: @IgorBeracka There are other potential solutions available if you are willing to limit yourself to a single platform or compiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to C++17, you can use the new [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) header. As the example there shows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

For a known file, the following may be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::string fileName("foo.txt"); // From example in question
    auto filePath = fs::path(fileName);
    std::cout << "Absolule path for " << fileName << " is " << fs::absolute(filePath) << '\n';
}
```

Note: I don't actually have a C++17 compiler to verify this on...

If you want a solution for earlier C++ versions, try [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path):

```
boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );
std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;
```

Comment: The OP wanted to know the full path of `fileName`, not of the executable.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yes, i wanted to know a full path of fileName, etc. C:\Directory\fileName

Comment: OK, updated with untested code for getting the full path.